# Is there a word or expression that describes a person who avoids speaking too loudly?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or expression that describes a person who avoids speaking too loudly?

As in: After dating a girl who spoke so loudly all the time I had to frequently remind her to use her "inside voice", it is such a pleasure to be with Sally because she is so _________ and easy on my ears.

Words like "polite" and "courteous" come to mind, but they refer to an overall demeanor that is pleasant to be around.  If there isn't a single word or expression that indicates that someone avoids speaking too loudly, what would be a succinct way to describe this?

Comment: I would simply reword your sentence: "..., it is such a pleasure to be with Sally and her quiet voice."

Answer (score 5):

The word I'd use is **soft-spoken**, which can be applied to people (as in your sentence) or voices:

> Speaking or said with a gentle, quiet voice.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/soft-spoken)</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  That is definitely closer to what I was looking for, more so that "courteous" or "polite".  The disadvantage to "soft-spoken" here is that it would also imply that a speaker is reserved in the meaning of what he says as well as in the delivery.

Answer (score -2):

modulates like... sally who modulates,and is easy

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Just check the word in a good dictionary and if you like the meanings, update the answer.